# Shortcut to TV channel in Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center

How can I make a Windows shortcut to a specific TV channel in Windows Media Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a couple of years too late for your question, but I just uploaded a project on CodePlex that lets you create desktop shortcuts to specific channels in Windows Media Center (and otherwise, automate channel changing via C#).

http://mediacentercommander.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a shortcut icon to your desktop that, when clicked, opens WMC and starts playing a specific TV channel?

Sorry, that's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a PowerShell script.  Something like...

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$proc = Start-Process "C:\Windows\ehome\ehshell.exe"
start-sleep -Milliseconds 10000 #Wait 10 sec while Media Center loads
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^T")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("7") #Channel 7
```